# Probability of a hand is void in at least 2 suits

Tags: probability, card-games

I was calculating for the following question:

In a card game what is the probability of that a hand of 13 cards is void in at least 2 suits.

I think :

$$1- \frac{ \binom{52}{13} -  4 \times \binom{39}{13}} { \binom{52}{13}}$$

but my answer is wrong.

Comment: What exactly is a "hand" in this context?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Card games consist of 4 type of cards. Each one is a hand.

Comment: In Poker, five cards make a hand. How many cards make _a hand_ in your game?

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that - if $4$ cards of a deck are randomly selected - at least $2$ of the $4$ suites are not presented by the cards? Anyway. Some things are not clear, and you should repair that by means of an edit of your question (not only by a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a hand has 13 cards then the probability that a hand is void in at least 2 suits is, 
$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\left(\binom{26}{13}-2\right)+4}{\binom{52}{13}}.$$
In fact a hand that is void in at least 2 suits will have two suits or one suit. In the first case
we choose the suits in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways and
the values in $\binom{26}{13}-2$ ways (we exclude the two cases where the cards are all of the same suit). In the second case we have to choose only one suit in $4$ ways.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why we are excluding 2 ways

Comment: @Harry When you choose 13 cards among the 26 cards of two suits then there are two cases where the suits are all the same: 13 cards of the first suit and 13 cards of the second suit.

Comment: @Harry, so a hand in your game has 13 cards. Is this true?

Comment: Thanks. Yes a hand in the game has 13 cards.